# How to include an SQL Server execution plan to a Stack Overflow question

Tags: discussion

If I have performance issues for an SQL Server query, I need to include the actual execution plan to my question. How can I do that?

Comment: Note: I actually know how to do this. I intend to get an answer from someone with better answering skills than me, so we can use this as a guide. Many sql server questions are performance questions that do not include it, and we keep copy-pasting something; let's make that something pretty. I haven't found something like this already - there is a how-to see, not include, the execution plan, here ( stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/… ) but it is more aligned to expaining it and maybe start figuring it out.

Comment: I've edited the [sql server's tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) to add some information about how to view the execution plan and how to share it, hope that helps.

Comment: This isn't really a meta question, tag wiki seems far more appropriate.

Comment: Related on Meta DBA.SE: [How do I provide an execution plan to someone for analysis?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/796)

Answer (score 9):

The plan should ideally be the "actual" execution plan (as opposed to "estimated" or pulled from cache) - though if it is not possible to collect an actual execution plan these *may* be sufficient.

If you are able to reproduce the issue in an environment where you can run queries in SSMS against it then the actual execution plan can be retrieved by enabling the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option on the Query menu then running the problem query. The graphical plan that is returned can be right clicked to get the option to view as XML or save as an XML file (with `.sqlplan` extension). Failing that it can also be gathered using [extended events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33657996/73226) but ideally you should be constructing an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue.

The plan should ideally be supplied in XML format. This provides information such as SQL Server build number, cardinality estimator version used, estimated vs actual row counts, and (in more recent builds) wait types and durations encountered throughout the execution, operator level IO stats and timings.

The requirement for XML means that it is unlikely to fit into the size limits of a question so it needs to be an offsite resource. Currently https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ would seem an obvious choice. As this is a free online service specialized for this task.

Answerers should include any relevant information gleaned from the execution plan in their answer itself. So it is possible to read standalone and not have to download the plan to follow the analysis. This also acts as insurance for the possibility that the offsite resource may become unavailable at some point in the future.

Comment: You can also get the actual execution plan in XML by using `SET STATISTICS XML ON` before your query (turn it `OFF` after if you need to).

Answer (score -18):

In SSMS build you query,

click the button shown here:

[image]

You will then see the execution plan

[image]

If there are optimization suggestions they will appear there such as new index suggestions

Comment: ohh god. why blue?

Comment: This seems to me like it only answers half the question (how to generate the execution plan) and leaves out the other half (how to include it in a Stack Overflow question). You show an image of a plan here, *perhaps* implying that somebody should include such an image into their question, but the [cross-site dupe](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/796/18607) suggests that there are other ways it could be provided (pasting the underlying XML or uploading the plan file itself to a file-sharing site) and you don't evaluate them or even explicitly come down on the side of using an image here.

Comment: @AmitJoshi some people just want to watch the world burn...

Comment: Question doesn't even make much sense. Just screen shot it if that is all he wants

Comment: That's a plan for a `SELECT TOP x *` query. How would the image look like when you have 10 joins and/or subqueries? Yeah, good luck with that image. Not sure why you would expect someone to have such a basic execution plan

Comment: The XML for the actual execution plan contains a **lot** of information not visible in the image, including estimated vs actual row counts, wait type statistics, operator level IO stats and timings. Plans should not be supplied as images if asking a question about query performance because then we cant see this information.

Comment: @AmitJoshi He's even added a blue outline over the blue header :) He's gone mad!

Comment: i see you know it alls couldnt provide ANY answer at all, gj guys and blue is the only way to go

Comment: The "paste the plan link" is great (answer above and accepted answer from Mark).   It seems a bit of an overreach to put this query down because it is the estimated and not the actual execution plan.  Right clicking anywhere on the estimate plan brings up the XML that would be required for a paste. SET STATISTICS XML ON is important here.